# Module of finite projective dimension and base change with respect to the completion

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring and let $M$ be an $\hat{R}$-module, where $\hat{R}$ denotes the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion of $R$. Suppose that $\operatorname{pd}_R(M)< \infty$. Does this imply $\operatorname{pd}_{\hat{R}}(M)< \infty$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. If $\operatorname{pd}_R(M)<\infty$, using flatness, one has $\operatorname{pd}_{\hat{R}}(M\otimes_R\hat{R})<\infty$. Tensoring $R\to \hat{R}$ by $M$, one has a map $M\to M\otimes_R\hat{R}$ and using the map $M\times \hat{R}\to M$ by $(m,a)\mapsto am$, we get a map $M\otimes_R\hat{R}\to M$, which gives a splitting $M\otimes_R\hat{R}=M\oplus N$ for some $N$. Since direct summand of a module of finite projective dimension must have finite projective dimension, we are done.

Comment: I think by using the same idea(splitting ), we can show that $\hat{R} \otimes_R \hat{R}=\hat{R}$ and so $M \otimes_R \hat{R}=M$ for all   $\hat{R}$-modules M.

Comment: $\hat{R}\otimes_R\hat{R}\neq\hat{R}$.

Comment: We have $\hat{R} \otimes_R \hat{R}= \hat{R} \oplus N$ for some $\hat{R}$-module $N$. Applying $- \otimes_{\hat{R}} k$,leads us to the result.

Comment: It is not true since $N$ is not finitely generated over $\hat{R}$. $N\otimes_{\hat{R}} k=0$ does not mean $N=0$.

Comment: If N is not finitely generated then $\hat{R} \otimes_R \hat{R}$ isn't too. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, of course I am assuming $R\neq \hat{R}$.

Comment: But I think $\hat{R} \otimes_R \hat{R}$ is a finitely generated $\hat{R}$- module and it is generated by $1_{\hat{R}} \otimes 1_{\hat{R}} $.

Comment: No, it is not. $\hat{R}\otimes_R\hat{R}/\hat{R}=\hat{R}/R\otimes_R\hat{R}$, where the inclusion of $\hat{R}$ in $\hat{R}\otimes_R\hat{R}$ is given by $1\otimes 1$. Since $\hat{R}/R\neq 0$, by faithful flatness, nor is this tensor product.