# On homological dimensions of finitely generated modules over a local ring and its completion

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay, formal-completions

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring. Let $\hat R$ be the $\mathfrak m$-adic completion of $R$ so we have a canonical map $R \to \hat R$, which makes $\hat R$ into a $R$-algebra, so every $\hat R$-module has a canonical $R$-module structure. My questions are the following:

(1) Let $M$ be a finitely generated $\hat R$-module such that inj$\dim_{\hat R} M <\infty$ , then is it true that inj$\dim_{R} M <\infty$ ?

(2) Let $M$ be a finitely generated $\hat R$-module such that proj$\dim_{ R} M <\infty$ , then is it true that proj$\dim_{\hat R} M <\infty$ ?

If need be, I'm willing to assume $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay and $M$ is a maximal Cohen-Macaulay $\hat R$-module .

Comment: Please see this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394915/module-of-finite-projective-dimension-and-base-change-with-respect-to-the-comple

Comment: @Mohammad Bagheri: agh great ... but that takes care of only the projective dimension case ...

Comment: I am not sure about the injective dimension case.

Comment: For the Gorenstein case, the injective version follows from the projective version by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3439453/12885 doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, (2)  is true irrespective of an assumption of finite generation.

I cannot find a reference anywhere for (1) in total generality, but as Ben said in the  comments, it holds over Gorenstein rings. This is the key step in my proof:

> **Theorem** (4.3.1 Weibel). Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism. If $M$ is an $S$-module, then as an $R$-module
>   $$\text{pd}_{R}(M)\leq \text{pd}_{S}(M)+\text{pd}_{R}(S).$$

Returning to your question, we have the following:

> **Corollary**. (1) holds if $R$ is Gorenstein, without the assumption of finite generation.

*Proof*. $R$ is Gorenstein $\iff \hat{R}$ is Gorenstein, so if $M$ is an $\hat{R}$-module such that $\text{id}_{\hat{R}}(M)<\infty$, then $\text{pd}_{\hat{R}}(M)<\infty$. We therefore have $\text{pd}_{R}(M)<\infty$ by the theorem, since $R$ is Gorenstein and $\hat{R}$ is flat over $R$. Using $R$ being Gorenstein again, we have $\text{id}_{R}(M)<\infty$.

---

For certain modules (1) also holds over non-Gorenstein local rings:

> **Lemma**. Let $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ be a noetherian local ring and $\hat{M}$ a finitely generated $\hat{R}$-module that is the completion of a finitely generated $R$-module, $M$. Then $\text{id}_{R}(M)<\infty \iff \text{id}_{\hat{R}}(\hat{M})<\infty.$

*Proof*.
If $A$ is any $R$-module, then for every $j\geq 0$ we have
$$\text{Ext}_{R}^{j}(k,A)=0 \iff \text{Ext}_{\hat{R}}^{j}(k,\hat{R}\otimes A)=0,$$
from the fact that $\hat{R}$ is faithfully flat over $R$ and $k\otimes \hat{R}\simeq \hat{R}/\mathfrak{m}\hat{R}\simeq k$.
Now, if $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module we have
\begin{align}
\text{id}_{R}(M)<\infty&\iff \text{Ext}_{R}^{j}(k,M)=0  \text{ for all }j>\text{depth}\,R
\\
&\iff \text{Ext}_{\hat{R}}^{j}(k,\hat{M})=0 \text{ for all }j>\text{depth}\,R=\text{depth}\,\hat{R}
\\
&\iff \text{id}_{\hat{R}}(\hat{M})<\infty.
\end{align}

---

Here are some related results that relate to injective dimension and injective modules under flat base change.

This first result is due to H.-B. Foxby and can be found in 
[Injective modules under flat base change](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-050-01/S0002-9939-1975-0409439-7/S0002-9939-1975-0409439-7.pdf):

> **Theorem**.
>   Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be a morphism of commutative rings such that $S$ is a flat $R$-module. Then if $E$ is an injective $R$-module, one has
>   $$\text{id}_{S}\,S\otimes_{R}E=\sup_{\mathfrak{p}\in\text{Ass}\,E}\text{id}_{F(\mathfrak{p})}\,F(\mathfrak{p})$$

Here $F(\mathfrak{p})=k(\mathfrak{p})\otimes_{R}S$ is the fibre of $f$ at $\mathfrak{p}$.

In particular, if one of the fibres is not Gorenstein, then $S\otimes -$ doesn't preserve finite injective dimension. Foxby also gives the example of localisation:

**Example**. Let $R$ be the homomorphic image of a Gorenstein ring. Then the fibres of $R\rightarrow\hat{R}$ are trivial, and $\text{dim}\,F(\mathfrak{p})\leq\max\{0,\text{dim}\,A/\mathfrak{p}-1\}.$

The local case is just CM rings with canonical module. This next result is due to Foxby and A. Thorup, found in [Minimal injective resolutions under flat base change](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1977-067-01/S0002-9939-1977-0453724-1/home.html). This is a corollary to the main result, but I'll call it a theorem here.

> **Theorem** Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ and $S$ be local rings and $f:R\rightarrow S$ a flat ring morphism of local rings. If $M$ is a finitely generated nonzero $R$-module, then
>   $$\text{id}_{S}(M\otimes_{R}S)= \text{id}_{R}(M)+\text{id}_{C}(C),$$
>   where $C=S/\mathfrak{m}S$. In particular, the left hand side is finite if and only if $\text{id}_{R}(M)<\infty$ and $C$ is Gorenstein.

Another paper with relevant results in is [Injective Modules under Faithfully Flat Ring Extensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7791) by L.W. Christensen and F. Koksal.

I'm sure there are many more that I have not mentioned or discovered that have equally interesting things to say about injective modules and dimension in this situation. Feel free to make edits to include anything further.