# Does the completion of a local Gorenstein ring has finite injective dimension over the original ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay, formal-completions, gorenstein

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a local Gorenstein ring and $\hat R$ be its $\mathfrak m$-adic completion. So we have a canonical map $R \to \hat R$ which makes $\hat R$ into an $R$-module. My question is: Does $\hat R$ have finite injective dimension as $R$-module ?

This is related to the injective dimension question in here [On homological dimensions of finitely generated modules over a local ring and its completion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436232/on-homological-dimensions-of-finitely-generated-modules-over-a-local-ring-and-it) . Notice that since $\hat R$ is Gorenstein, we do have inj$\dim_{\hat R} \hat R <\infty$ and I'm asking whether it is true that inj$\dim_R \hat R <\infty$ or not.

Comment: The answer is positive. Use 3.2.19 of the book "Relative Homological Algebra" and note that ${\rm pd} \, E(R/{\frak m})$ is finite.

Comment: @Mohammad Bagheri: why does $E(R/\mathfrak m)$ have finite projective dimension ? (It is not finitely generated ... )

Comment: See proposition 9.5.22 or proposition 9.1.7 of the book "Relative Homological Algebra".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R$ is Gorenstein and $M$ is an $R$-module then
$$
\text{inj dim}_{R}\,M<\infty \iff \text{flat dim}_{R}\,M<\infty \iff \text{proj dim}_{R}\,M<\infty.$$
Over a commutative noetherian local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$, the completion $\hat{R}$ is a (faithfully) flat $R$-module.

Therefore over a Gorenstein local ring $R$ the module $\hat{R}$ has finite injective dimension, as Mohammad Bagheri stated.